# Mongoose - Find Model by the author's id

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to find all the post created by a given author via the author's id but I keep getting an empty array

below are the model and the get request

````
let campgroundSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    image:String,
    location:String,
    lat:Number,
    lng:Number,
    price:String,
    description:String,
    createdAt: {type:Date, default:Date.now},
    author:{
        id:{
            type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref:'User'
        },
        username:String,
    },
    comments:[{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'Comment'
    }]
});

let Campground = mongoose.model('campground',campgroundSchema);```

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:String,
    password:String,
    firstName:String,
    lastName:String,
    email:String,
    profileImage:String,
    isAdmin:{type:Boolean, default:false},
    followers:[
        {
            type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref:'User'
        }
    ],
    notifications:[{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'Notification'
    }]
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
````

Hi do I get an array of all the campgrounds by a given author via the author's id The idea is to render a user profile page with user's details as stored in the user model as well as the number of posts the user has created.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to return all of the campgrounds by the author id.  If that's the case, your query is looking for the wrong id.

```
User.findById(req.params.id)
```

is going to find the documents in the User collection matching on the native _id that Mongo automatically generates.

If you want to find the campgrounds matching on author id, your query should look something like:

```
User.find({ author.id: req.params.id })
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The idea is to render a user profile page with user's details as stored in the user model as well as the number of posts the user has created. I thought to first find the user the find the associated campgrounds by author id which is the same as the found user's id.

Comment: Take a look at mongoose populate function https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

This may be what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks this helped

Answer (score 0):

simple search in post collection

```
Post.find({author.id: req.params.id},(err, posts) => 
    {
       ....
    })
```

Comment: The idea is to render a user profile page with user's details as stored in the user model as well as the number of posts the user has created. I thought to first find the user the find the associated campgrounds by author id which is the same as the found user's id.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

```
router.get('/users/:id',(req,res) => {
     User.findById(req.params.id).populate('posts').exec((err,foundUser)=>{
        if (err) {
            req.flash('error_msg',"Something went wrong");
            res.redirect('/');
        } else {
            Campground.find({'author.id':foundUser.id},(err,foundUser_campgrounds)=>{
                res.render('users/show', {userProfile:foundUser, userCampgrounds:foundUser_campgrounds});
            });
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Where posts `posts` defined in the question schema?

Answer (score -2):

```
const User=require('./models/user');
const Campground = require('./models/campgrounds');

app.get('/profile/:id',(req,res) => {
    const user = User.findById(req.params.id);
    const camp= Campground.find({author:user._id});
    res.send(camp);
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 